# React Navigation 3.x Require cycle warning

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

New to React)

Since upgrade to React Navigation to  3.x i've got this warning in a console

```
[23:12:54] Require cycle: src/navigation/DrawerNavigator.js -> src/navigation/index.js -> src/navigation/DrawerNavigator.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

is it anybody know what does it mean?

Comment: Having this same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation given by @kelset [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20841#issuecomment-427289537)  is pretty clear.

> *---> File A wants something from file B -> file B wants something from file C -> file C wants something from file A ---*
>
> There is a "circle" being created, and thus the warning says this may
> lead to uninitialized values.

In your case, this mean that DrawerNavigation import/require something from a file that have itself an import/require for DrawerNavigation. This is the "circle" created.

It's a warning and not an error, so your app should run perfectly without problems.